# Fetch records that are not greater than provided quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

Quantity comes as a parameter so I have to fetch records only up to `@quantity`. What I tried after `FROM` is not so meaningful so given below is my query where I need to implement that condition. I tried both in `WHERE` and using `HAVING` but unable:

```
SELECT prod_id,
    product,
    technology,
    price,
    quantity
FROM tbl_product
------SUM(quantity) <= @quantity
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
prod_id product technology  price   quantity
1       M1      ST          25.33   10
2       M2      ST          23.65   50
3       S1      ST          54.32   90
4       S2      PY          21.435  30
5       S3      PY          98.64   110
```

IF @quantity = 150 then first 3 records should be fetched.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to make your problem more clearer?

Comment: what are the input and the output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a cumulative sum(based on the "fetch up to" in your question), which is most efficiently done using window function.

try:

```
with cumulative as (
    SELECT prod_id,
      product,
      technology,
      price,
      quantity,
      sum(quantity) over (order by <order column>) as cumulative_quantity
    FROM tbl_product
) 
select 
    prod_id,
    product,
    technology,
    price,
    quantity
from cumulative where cumulative_quantity <= @quantity;
```

You'll need to provide an order column to indicate what ordering do you want the cumulative summation to use.

So when @quantity = 150, your result will be:

```
prod_id product technology  price   quantity
1       M1      ST          25.33   10
2       M2      ST          23.65   50
3       S1      ST          54.32   90
```

(if you are using prod_id as the order by column).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but it's not giving expected result.

Comment: It's returning first three rows which is right but in the last row the quantity is 150 where as we have 90 in actual. however I have used `prod_id` in the `<order column>`

Comment: Try using the edited code above. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to take the first N records as ordered by `prod_id` whose cumulative sum is less than `@quantity`, then you can try the following query:

```
SELECT
    prod_id,
    product,
    technology,
    price,
    quantity
FROM tbl_product t1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(t2.quantity) FROM tbl_product t2
       WHERE t2.prod_id <= t1.prod_id) < @quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on product you can find as below

```
SELECT distinct prod_id,
       product,
       technology,
       price,
FROM tbl_product
where product in (
SELECT product
FROM tbl_product
GROUP BY product
HAVING SUM(quantity) <= @quantity)
```